# Alternatives to connect to ORACLE database server without install the Oracle client

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-7

i am looking for an Delphi component to connect to an ORACLE database server in an direct way without install the oracle client.

i knew the [Oracle Data Access (ODAC)](http://www.devart.com/odac/) from [DevArt](http://www.devart.com/). there are any other component with this capability?

> ODAC offers two connection modes to
>   the Oracle server: connection through
>   the Oracle Call Interface in Client
>   mode **and direct connection over TCP/IP
>   in Direct mode**. ODAC-based database
>   applications are easy to deploy, do
>   not require installation of other data
>   provider layers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the Oracle client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no other Delphi Win32 libraries allowing to connect to Oracle without the installed Oracle Client. And, IMHO, that is correct, because:

1. OCI (Oracle Call Interface) is quite complex piece of software. I will say, it is most complex closed sourced DBMS Call Level Interface in the World. And it is changing from version to version. Oracle has official rule - the Oracle Client v X supports Oracle Server v X-1 ... X+1. Because even such company as Oracle, dont want to spend resources to support and test all the protocol nuances across all possible versions. So, I dont think, that DevArt ever will implement 99.9% stable Oracle SQL*Net protocol implementation. And the INet posts proof that ...
2. AFAIK, the ODAC Net mode does not support some of the Oracle Client important features and has some important limitations. Although it works well for simple data access scenarious.
3. If you will purchase Oracle support, then it will decline all your support requests, if they will know, that you are not using official client software. That is just Oracle rule.
4. If you dislike to install and tune the full scale Oracle Client, then you can just use Oracle Instant Client. Which does not require install or setup procedure. And you will be in safety in case of the different data access scenarious and Oracle Server versions.

PS: Although I may be considered as a biased person :)

Comment: just a nit-pick: there is no English word "scenarious."  Based on the context, it appears that you meant "scenarios."

Comment: +1 because OCI is big, but is the one to be used for best performance, and better support (e.g. Client-side caching is a complex feature, handled only by OCI AFAIK). And +1 because you quoted [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client). I just [finished a direct wrapper to OCI](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/09/SynDBOracle%3A-Open-Source-native-Oracle-access), working with Oracle Instant Client. Works like a charm, without any Setup to run! Of course, OCI is big, comparing to the Delphi app, but it works fast...

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Allround Automations](http://www.allroundautomations.com/doa.html) Direct Oracle Access, it do require Oracle SQL*Net or Net8. but is a brilliant component suite.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is ODAC, and it's working very nice, I have been  using it since years without getting any problem with the direct mode.

there's some limitation with the direct mode, but most of users will not get these limitations with their application.